# How to Deserialize XML inside XML?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I have this XML:

```
<Record>
    <ID>123</ID>
    <Question>Question goes here...</Question>
    <Answer>Answer goes here...</Answer>
    <ExtentedAnswer>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?&gt;&lt;ExtendedResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" DataType="12" xmlns="http://schemas.example.com/"&gt;&lt;ComplexText&gt;&lt;CityStateZip&gt;&lt;City&gt;Clifton&lt;/City&gt;&lt;State&gt;VA&lt;/State&gt;&lt;Zip&gt;20124&lt;/Zip&gt;&lt;Country&gt;US&lt;/Country&gt;&lt;/CityStateZip&gt;&lt;/ComplexText&gt;&lt;/ExtendedResponse&gt;</ExtentedAnswer>
</Record>
```

Deserialize works fine, but I get ExtentedAnswer as String. Is it possible to Deserialize XML inside ExtentedAnswer in one go. I know I can Deserialize the ExtentedAnswer separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have tackled this issue at our workplace. In our specific case, the problem was to convert the text with XSLT, which was an utter pain, but is indeed possible. In code it's less complicated, as suggested by other posters, just substitute the escape codes for `<` and `>` and parse it with a normal parser.

However it appears that you want a single-step solution. I doubt very much that the standard XML Serializer will be able to do this, since it has no knowledge of which elements contain escaped xml content. The escaped text is specifically to stop xml parsers from detecting it, so a hand-rolled solution is probably your only option. Your class should implement `IXmlSerializable` and perform the text conversion itself.

Finally, I would strongly recommend that if you have any control over the process that is creating this data in the first place that you **don't** store escaped xml and find another solution. It is a nuisance to work with and I can't think of any situation where it would be genuinely necessary.

Comment: Thanks. Sadly, I am not in-charge of generating XMLs. Well, as it seems now, to just make it work, I will be doing it separately and later on will roll on IXmlSerializable implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to replace `&amp;lt;` with the `<` character and `&amp;gt;` with the `>` character. This will then give you a string that you can use with an XML reader.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can do but **xml** should store the **ExtentedAnswer** as follows:-

```
  <ExtentedAnswer>
    <![CDATA[
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <ExtendedResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" DataType="12" xmlns="http://schemas.example.com/">
      <ComplexText>
        <CityStateZip>
          <City>Clifton</City>
          <State>VA</State>
          <Zip>20124</Zip>
          <Country>US</Country>
        </CityStateZip>
      </ComplexText>
    </ExtendedResponse>
    ]]>
  </ExtentedAnswer>
```

Comment: Yes. It will work. Thanks. But I am not in-charge of generating XML.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible if you make it possible.  If you just do this in one place then I would just do it separately, but if you have a need to do this in many places then you could write a class that would do this for you and then use that wherever you need it.

Comment: Well, I know it can be done separately. I was just wondering if this is possible to do deserialize at once and inside XML part can be aggregated to root.

Comment: Yeah I understand.  I just mean that if you don't find a way to do it in one step like you'd like then make sure you encapsulate the steps to do it in one place rather than doing the multiple steps each time you need to read the xml data.